# ASP.Net GridView Edit/Update/Cancel/Delete Events On RowClick

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

We've got an ASP.Net application that contains a GridView Control that contains row edit functionality.

This allows a user to Edit, Delete, Or Cancel editing on a particular row.

For Example Read Only Mode Looks Like This:
[image]

And Edit Mode Looks Like this:
[image]

The mechanism that allows the user to enter Edit mode is based on an Edit Button in a template column that changes the selected row from a read only row to an editable row using a RowEditing event something like this:

```
 protected void grdOfMine_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grdOfMine.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    ReBindDataGrid();
}
```

Canceling is pretty much the opposite where we have a button click event that changes the row back to ready only mode:

```
 protected void grdOfMine_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grdOfMine.EditIndex = -1;
    ReBindDataGrid();
}
```

(Apologies to those who are already familiar with this aspect of ASP.Net forms development.)

We've also created a footer row that allows a user to add a new row:

[image]

We're looking for a way to extend the ASP.Net GridView control do this without using the buttons to fire the events.

For example:

1. Allow a user to enter edit mode for a row, by clicking in a cell of any given row and update the selected record say, on an Enter keyboard input event (Instead of the Edit Button).
2. Delete a record say, on a delete keyboard input event (Instead of the Delete Button).
3. Add a record in a similar fashion (Instead of the Add Button).

We were attempting this functionality using Infragistics controls, however we had a very tough time getting these to work, so we decided not to use them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am working on asp.net gridview on webforms and using Gridview RowCommand method of GridView OnRowCommand event for the Buttons View, Edit & Update inside TemplateField.

```
if (e.CommandName == "EditContract") {

                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
                int SerialNo = (int)gvContract.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;

                int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
                gvContract.SelectRow(rowIndex);

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spContractEdit", myObj.DbConnect()))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RoleName", SqlDbType.Char).Value = Session["RoleName"];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitName", SqlDbType.Char).Value = Session["UnitName"];
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContrSerialNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = SerialNo;

                    dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                    DataTable DtContract = new DataTable();
                    dAdapter.Fill(DtContract);
}

 if (e.CommandName == "UpdateContract") {

                lblMessage.Text = "";
                lblFile.Text = "";

                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
                int SerialNo = (int)gvContract.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spContractUpdate", myObj.DbConnect()))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContrNewRev", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddNewOrRevised.SelectedValue;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContractTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtContractTitle.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FinancerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddFinancer.SelectedValue;
}
```

This code is working fine when the page loads first time but has 2 problems after that. i.e. 1. It is editing and updating data when the page gets load for the first time but when I try to edit the same row or any other then it doesn't. I know it is because I have defined the !Page.IsPostback method on the Page_Load event but I do not know how to tackle this situation. 2. Problem is How to restrict the gridview row to update only that data whose row is selected?

Please suggest me a solution.

[GridView Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOAjD.png)